# MapKit Animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I'm trying to use UIView animations for animating the camera in MapKit, but it seems to be skipping to the end.

```
MKMapCamera *cam = [[MKMapCamera alloc] init];
cam.centerCoordinate = location.coordinate;
cam.altitude = 10E5;
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:1 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        mapView.camera = cam;
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:10.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        mapView.camera.altitude = 10E10;

    }];

} completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs: "Assigning a new camera to this property updates the map immediately and without animating the change. If you want to animate changes in camera position, use the setCamera:animated: method instead."

You could try `setCamera:animated:`, but getting the time it takes for the first animation to complete might not be possible.

Comment: Are there any ways to zoom into a map, and zoom somewhere else that allows this?